# Reshaping a 3D array of shape (K, M, N) to 2D array of shape (n_rows * M, n_cols * N) with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, einops

I was trying to reshape a 3D array/tensor `arr` of shape (K, M, N) in `numpy` (where each (M, N) subarray could be an image for instance) to a 2D of shape (n_rows * M, n_cols * N).

Obviously, I ensure `K = n_rows * n_cols` beforehand.

I tried all the possible permutations (after scrolling on similar topics on SO),

```
 for perm in itertools.permutations([0, 1, 2], 3):
        test = arr.transpose(perm).reshape((n_rows * M, n_cols * N))
```

but unsuccessfully so far.

However, using `einops` like this,

```
test = ein.rearrange(arr, '(r c) h w -> (r h) (c w)', r=n_rows, c=n_cols)
```

it yields the expected result.

Is there a straightforward way to achieve this with numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deducing from what I think the ein syntax means (new package to me, so unverified whether this is the produced output you expect):

```
import numpy as np

K, M, N = 6, 4, 5
n_rows, n_cols = 3, 2

arr = np.arange(K * M * N).reshape(K, M, N)

out = (
    arr                                  # (r c) h w
    .reshape(n_rows, n_cols, M, N)       # r c h w
    .swapaxes(1, 2)                      # r h c w
    .reshape(n_rows * M, n_cols * N)     # (r h) (c w)
)
```

out:

```
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3,   4,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24],
       [  5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  25,  26,  27,  28,  29],
       [ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34],
       [ 15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39],
       [ 40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64],
       [ 45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  65,  66,  67,  68,  69],
       [ 50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74],
       [ 55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79],
       [ 80,  81,  82,  83,  84, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104],
       [ 85,  86,  87,  88,  89, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109],
       [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114],
       [ 95,  96,  97,  98,  99, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]])
```

Comment: yup, your guess is correct